# Google Sheets - Date Format Display Issues

Tags: date, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm currently building dashboards in Google Sheets and have run into a consistent issue with dates being displayed as a number opposed to a date format. EX: `43626` opposed to `6/11/19`.

This data is being pulled from form sheet into a database, then queried into the dashboard spreadsheet where it is coming through as a number sequence opposed to readable date format. Currently have tried to use the `DATEVALUE` to reformat, as well as attempted to reformat the cell into a date format in both dashboard and database locations, with no luck.

//What I've tried

`=TargetCell`

> `43626`

`=DATEVALUE(TargetCell)`

> `43626`

`=TargetCell` //Reformatted as any Date format

> `43626`

I was expecting the following

`=DATEVALUE(TargetCell)`

> `6/11/19`

OR:

`=TargetCell` //Reformatted as any Date format

> `6/11/19`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got it wrong... function **`DATEVALUE`** creates **`43626`** from **`6/11/2019`**

if you want to reverse it you need to use either:

- internal custom date formatting (does not work all the times)
- **`TEXT`** formula like: `=TEXT(43626, "m/d/yy")`
- `QUERY` parameter `format` like: `=QUERY(A:B, "format A 'm/d/yy'", 0)`
- or `QUERY` parameter `toDate` like: `=QUERY(A:B, "toDate(A)", 0)`

**https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#top_of_page**

Comment: Opps, you are definitely right, I was using the DATEVALUE function backwards. The Text formula is what I have opted to use as I am querying 700~ columns and selecting them all. Text formula worked well! Thank you for your help.